# Adaptation for different displays of androids

Tags: android

How should I resize text, button images, etc. to different screens? For example, to make text or images look readable on both large and small screens. It is written on the Internet that you need to create folders with the prefixes hdpi, mdpi, and so on, but this is not an adaptation, but a simple creation of several xml markup and thereby takes up extra memory space. I would like to use something like percentage or are there other solutions?

Answer (score 1):

I recommend this library to you https://github.com/intuit/sdp

> An android lib that provides a new size unit - sdp (scalable dp). This size unit scales with the screen size. It can help Android developers with supporting multiple screens.

All you need is to add its dependencies
for none Text sizes use this

```
dependencies {
implementation 'com.intuit.sdp:sdp-android:1.0.6'
}
```

And this an example of it on XML

```
  <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/give_us_a_review_landmine_main_layout"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/_27sdp"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/_43sdp"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/_43sdp"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/_50sdp" >
```

---

for fonts size use this

```
dependencies {
 implementation 'com.intuit.ssp:ssp-android:1.0.6'
}
```

this example for using the text size

```
 <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Intuit"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:textSize="@dimen/_40ssp"/>
```